# Recurring code in Django views: how to avoid repetition?

Tags: python, django

For many - but not all - of my views I have to do some validation to make sure the user that is logged in has access to the object they are trying to access. For 30+ views I have this code:

```
def whatever_view_name(request, id, access_id):
    check = Access.objects.filter(user=request.user, id=access_id)
    if check:
        access_object = check[0]
    else:
        return redirect(reverse("create_new_access_object"))

    .... and now my view-specific code will follow ...
```

So I need to check if a particular database record (Access) exists for this particular user. This code is repeated a lot, which does not seem to be right. I've been thinking about using middleware, but there are two problems: a) I need to use this object in the view (see variable `access_object` so I fear I'd have to query it twice if I put it in the middleware), and b) I don't need to do this ALWAYS so I wonder how to only run it for some views and not all if this is middleware.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Write a decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a decorator for this:

```
from functools import wraps

def check_access(function):
  @wraps(function)
  def wrap(request, id, access_id, *args, **kwargs):
        check = Access.objects.filter(user=request.user, id=access_id)
        if check.exists():
             return function(request, id, access_id, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect(reverse("create_new_access_object"))
  return wrap

# usage

@check_access
def whatever_view_name(request, id, access_id):
     return ...
```

Answer (score 1):

One way that I can think of is using inheritance. We can refactor out the common stuff into a super view class and then extend the same in child view classes.

Something like this :

We can have a super class like this

```
class AccessVerifiedView(View):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        check = Access.objects.filter(user=request.user, id=kwargs["access_id"])
        if check:
            access_object = check[0]
            self.verified_get(access_object)
        else:
            return redirect(reverse("create_new_access_object"))

    def verified_get(self, access_object):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Then we can extend that class and the use in our views.

```
class MyView(AccessVerifiedView):
    def verified_get(self, access_object):
        return access_object
```

This approach see bit more readable. Anyone seeing the code can see the super class and understand the code flow.

Other few ways to do it is

1. Decorator : We can have a decorator which will do the same thing. And then we can decorate the view which we want to verify.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a harder time fully understanding how this works so I ended up implementing the decorator instead.